# Conditional Client Side Validation?

Tags: xpages

I have a radio button group that gets it's values using an @Dblookup.  In addition to the name to appear in the radio button group, the document also has a field to determine if another field on the xPage should be displayed or not.

If the field is displayed then it should be required.

I can do the conditional validation just fine in SSJS using an @DbLookup to lookup the document selected in the radio button group.

But I would like to be able to do it CS so it is faster and so it looks like my other validations.   Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I found Stephen's blog http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7qg88xand see he recommends server side validation anyway for "real" validation. Should I just continue with my server side validation?

Comment: use the client-side validation as "assistance", there should be also a server-side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a field is not rendered then the node will not exist in the DOM. Your CS javascript would need to examine the DOM and look for the node, normally by looking for a specific ID. As Xpages changes the ID's sent to the browser your validation function would either need to be computed so it would know what ID to look for or you would need to look for it in some other unique way ( like add a css class name to just that field and then do a DOM search for nodes with that class name )

Once you can determine if the field has been rendered then you can run your usual CS validation routine against the other field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using client-side validation throughout your app, setting the required property on the field should achieve what you need.

If not, it may be worth looking at the Extension Library Dojo Validation Text Box. All the Extension Library Dojo control run client-side validation, even if validation is set as server-side at application level. Bear in mind that for the Dojo Validation Text Box, just setting the required property is not enough. You need to add more specific validation.

After that, the key is to ensure the partial refresh event on your radio group is set to skip validation. I haven't tried, but I believe that should achieve what you need.